# Replace and Delete when fetching some string in the same regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

My Input:

```
$str = 'In order to study the opportunity cost of allocating time to the less beneficial act, we need appropriate schedules of reinforcement description <?processing-instruction \value{$$@@%}?> list we need appropriate schedules of reinforcement';

my $get_val = ($str=~m/<\?processing\-instruction\s*\\value\{([^\}\?>]*)\}\?>/gi)[0];

print $get_val;
```

However I need to delete the whole processing instruction tag while finding the same. Is it possible on the same pattern?

I tried this however not success.

```
my ($get_val) = ($str=~s/<\?processing\-instruction\s*\\value\{([^\}\?>]*)\}\?>//gi)[0];

print $get_val;
```

The above output prints '1'. It would be appreciate if someone could help on this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @toolic: while matching this are success however when replacing the same it won't print.

Comment: The Substitution-Operator in perl returns the number of substitutions made, unlike the matching operator which returns a list of the machted and collected elements.

Comment: See `perldoc perlop` for a more complete explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the substitution is successful, then the value you want will be in `$1`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $str = 'In order to study the opportunity cost of allocating time to the less beneficial act, we need appropriate schedules of reinforcement description <?processing-instruction \value{$$@@%}?> list we need appropriate schedules of reinforcement';

if ($str =~ s/<\?processing\-instruction\s*\\value\{([^\}\?>]*)\}\?>//gi) {
  say $1;
}

say $str;
```

Output:

```
$$@@%
In order to study the opportunity cost of allocating time to the less beneficial act, we need appropriate schedules of reinforcement description  list we need appropriate schedules of reinforcement
```

Comment: Yes. I need to learn this type of logic and presence of thinking in my code. Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<\?processing-instruction.*?\?>
```

Replace by empty string

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/sG5GMI/1)

Perl Code Sample:

```
use strict;

my $str = 'In order to study the opportunity cost of allocating time to the less beneficial act, we need appropriate schedules of reinforcement description <?processing-instruction \\value{$$@@%}?> list we need appropriate schedules of reinforcement';
my $regex = qr/<\?processing-instruction.*?\?>/p;
my $subst = '';

my $result = $str =~ s/$regex/$subst/rg;

print $result;
```

[Run the code here](http://ideone.com/DApym2)